# LSI replace disk in raid1 with larger drives, how to expand raid to use free space

Tags: raid, lsi, fdisk

LSI MegaRAID SAS 9240-8i

Situation: 2 - 128GB drives in a raid1
I've replaced each drive, one at a time to let the raid rebuild.  The raid now consists of
2 - 256GB drives in raid1

```
    Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/vg_node-LV_ROOT   4.8G  1.3G  3.3G  29% /
    tmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
    /dev/sda1             917G  107G  765G  13% /backup
    /dev/sdb1             477M  102M  350M  23% /boot
    /dev/mapper/vg_node-LV_VZ     108G   86G   17G  84% /vz
```

I've expanded the raid:

```
    MegaCli64 -LdExpansion -p100 -Lall -aAll

    Adapter 0 -- Virtual Drive Information:
    Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
    Name                :
    RAID Level          : Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
    Size                : 237.968 GB
```

I have searched for hours and hours and can only find how to extend the actual partition but I can only find how to do it when adding new drives, not replacing them.  I need to expand /dev/mapper/vg_node-LV_VZ when using fdisk its still showing 128GB.

```
   Disk /dev/sdb: 127.5 GB, 127473287168 bytes
```

Comment: So you are looking for a way to expand the Linux LV group to use the additional space, and the fact that the disks are on a LSI 9240 is merely incidental?

Comment: Not sure what your asking sorry, are you asking that because you think a LV ontop of a hardware raid is redundant or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out, I needed to reboot the server after expanding the raid size, after I rebooted fdisk was able to see the new space.

Answer (score 1):

If your array is not bootable, you can also try to update device size by command:

echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/rescan